# Why my onload function is not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on api to generate random quotes. its working fine but i want to generate a random quotes as soon as page load.

```
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('onload', loadData);
document.getElementById('getQuote').addEventListener('click', loadData);

    function loadData() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/', true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById('quote-message').innerHTML = `<h1>${data[0].quote}</h1>`;
                document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = `<h3>${data[0].author}</h3>`;
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: `addEventListener('load'` ... not onload - also, do you have an element with ID == `load`?

Comment: place the `loadData` function definition above &
`document.addEventListener('onload',loadData)` will do the trick

Comment: @VeteranLK `function` declarations in JS are hoisted (moved to the top of scope), so it's perfectly valid to use the function name before it's defined

Comment: yes i have ID = load in my html code. @JaromandaX

Comment: what sort of element is it? what that has a `load` event? i.e. when do you expect this `load` event to fire?

Comment: div element. it fired should when my div element load

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Use `window.onload` to launch a script on document load:

```
window.onload = loadData;
```

Your full code will then look like

```
window.onload = loadData;
document.getElementById('getQuote').addEventListener('click', loadData);

function loadData() {
 // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. but i have some queries. why my addeventlistener was not working?

Comment: because the `onload` event does not happen to the `id=load` element, but to the `window` element. So you would have to use `window.addEventListener('load', loadData);` (note that the syntax is `load` and not `onload`)

Answer (score -2):

i guess your question is, why the function is not working when the page loads, try enclosing your function loadData in `$(document).ready()`. A function enclosed in `$(document).ready()`will execute when the page is done loading.

edit: correction not `load`, `ready` thanks.

Comment: document does not have a load property you can use like that

Comment: correction, that requires `jquery` - which is not asked for in the question